# PowerShell | TXT Contents to Object

Tags: powershell

Thank you for all the help I've gotten till now. I'm trying to challenge what I am learning with weird ideas. I'm trying to read through a TXT files and trying to convert them into Custom Objects in memory to manipulate later.

Contents of TXT file - there could be more "blocks"

```
  Object GUID:  86dabdb1-cdc7-421c-a58e-7c2cb55b1dba
  Name:         ScannerSchduler
  Location:     \\?\C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows Defender\
  Type:         file
  Status:       stored
  Store time:   Wed Nov 10 11:47:55 2021 (1636525075)
  Threat GUID:  b9d9575c-4723-4df3-b9ee-5d97a1d5b8bf
  Threat name:  Troj/MineJob-A

  Object GUID:  3eeeb91c-731e-4e03-a55e-4b200df17805
  Name:         WindowsParentalControlsSettings
  Location:     \\?\C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\
  Type:         file
  Status:       stored
  Store time:   Wed Nov 10 11:47:58 2021 (1636525078)
  Threat GUID:  b9d9575c-4723-4df3-b9ee-5d97a1d5b8bf
  Threat name:  Troj/MineJob-A
```

2 white spaces in the beginning but we can Trim() right.

My target custom object which is an array of objects,

```
$Objects = @() 

ForEach ($a in $Array)
{
    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Object_GUID" -Value $var[1]
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value ??
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Location" -Value ??
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Type" -Value ??
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value ??
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Store_time" -Value ??
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Threat_GUID" -Value ??
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Threat_Name" -Value ??
    $schtasks += $object
}
```

I feel embarrassed to ask for help but this is not "homework". I don't know how to inculcate the scripting mind and think of ways. I've read a book, taken few courses but the best way is to seek challenges and I keep failing at tiny ones like these.

The contents of $Array will be lines containing information. How can I Foreach that split each line into two Name:Type combination.

```
Where-Object {$_.length -gt 0} | Foreach-Object {
    $var = $_.split(':',2).trim()
    New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]
    Write-Host ($var[0] + " = " + $var[1])
```

The above can give me Name:Value pair for each line it finds. But I'm unable to nest it inside something that can create an object for me. I'll keep trying on my own.

Comment: That looks like list-formatted output from PowerShell itself - any particular reason you're writing this data to file and then re-importing it?

Comment: What did put that data there in the first place ? As Mathias said, it looks suspiciously like you might have exported ps objects to a text file. If so, consider changing the way you eport your data by using `ConvertTo-Json` before sending it to the file, then `ConvertFrom-Json` when you import it back. You'll have a custom object from the data built for you without any manual parsing of data.

Comment: It was a very good suggestion but, the output is from an EXE and I failed to try and get it to parse. 
$test1 = iex("C:\1Tools\Safestore\ssr64.exe -dbpath=`".\Safestore.db`" -pass=$password -l")
$test1  | ConvertTo-Json test.json
$test1.gettype()

Comment: @Origami As an aside: you don't need `iex` to invoke your exe - use the call operator `&` instead (`& "C:\1Tools\Safestore\ssr64.exe" -dbpath=...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the property list is always in order, you can use the `Object GUID:` line as an anchor for new objects:

```
$data = @'
  Object GUID:  86dabdb1-cdc7-421c-a58e-7c2cb55b1dba
  Name:         ScannerSchduler
  Location:     \\?\C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows Defender\
  Type:         file
  Status:       stored
  Store time:   Wed Nov 10 11:47:55 2021 (1636525075)
  Threat GUID:  b9d9575c-4723-4df3-b9ee-5d97a1d5b8bf
  Threat name:  Troj/MineJob-A

  Object GUID:  3eeeb91c-731e-4e03-a55e-4b200df17805
  Name:         WindowsParentalControlsSettings
  Location:     \\?\C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\
  Type:         file
  Status:       stored
  Store time:   Wed Nov 10 11:47:58 2021 (1636525078)
  Threat GUID:  b9d9575c-4723-4df3-b9ee-5d97a1d5b8bf
  Threat name:  Troj/MineJob-A
'@ -split '\r?\n' 

$objects = $data |ForEach-Object -Process {
  # always trim leading and trailing whitespace from line
  $_ = $_.Trim()

  if($_ -like 'Object GUID:*'){
    # first line in new block, output current object if any
    if($properties.Count){
      [pscustomobject]$properties
    }
    # ... then start processing new object
    $properties = [ordered]@{}
  }

  if($_ -like '*:*'){
    # extract name/value pair, trim again
    $name,$value = $_.Split(':') |ForEach-Object Trim
    # add value to property table
    $properties[$name] = $value
  }
} -End {
  # do we still have data collected for the last block in the sequence? output the last object too then
  if($properties.Count){
    [pscustomobject]$properties
    $properties = $null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, Mathias. I'm sorry but something's amiss.

$properties | Get-Member -MemberType Property

It does not give me properties such as "Object GUID", "Threat Name" etc
Also the $properties.count stays zero. 
Side note, I didn't know we can use $_ independently, I know it was a "temp" system variable. Thank you.

Comment: @Origami `$properties` is just a temporary dictionary, not the final object you want. I've updated the answer to collect all the resulting objects to a variable `$objects`

Comment: Silly me. mind = blown. (I aim to become 10 percent as good as you and I'll be happy) Just last question - where in the logic did we ensure we don't keep adding duplicating objects in the array if I keep re-running the script in ISE/PS?

Comment: @Origami There's no such protection in place :) Assuming the `Object GUID` values are indeed unique, you can probably deduplicate a set with `$objects = $objects |Sort-Object 'Object GUID' -Unique`

Comment: Trying hard to understand the logic but I hate to waste your time here. Is there a possibility of more comments? I mean it works so well I have no complaints. But when it comes to Custom Objects, I think if I can understand the flow here, this topic would be absolutely clear to me. No pressure.

Comment: The "flow" is very simple: We loop through the file and collect related name-value pairs into a temporary dictionary `$properties`. Every time we encounter the start of a new block (starting with `Object GUID:`) or the end of the file we output an object based on the name-value pairs collected so far (`[pscustomobject]$properties`), and then start over.

Comment: I understand. I googled about -Process and -End (how this only executes once). -Process and -End both blocks are executing when we piped the $Data into it, right? Just curious why was there a need to add "last block in the sequence?" and how exactly the data was "pushed" into the variable :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239281/discussion-between-origami-and-mathias-r-jessen).